# How to built an abstract matrix?

Tags: math-mode, matrices

I want to built a matrix like the picture:
[image]
Have a trial:

```
\begin{displaymath}
 \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
 b_{11} & \ldots & b_{1j} & \ldots & b_{1j} \\
 b_{21} & \ldots & x_{22} & \ldots & b_{1j}\\
 \vdots & \ldots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots\\
 b_{n1} & \ldots & x_{nj} & \ldots & b_{ns}
 \end{array} \right)
\end{displaymath}
```

However, it didn't work. Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I'd use `bmatrix` and/or `pmatrix` from the [`amsmath` package](http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf) (see p.10 of the link) for what you're doing.

Comment: Also, it always helps if you could post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: There are five columns in your array, however, you only provided three columns (`\begin{array}{ccc}`). This is the key.

Comment: BTW, `\ldots` is better than `\cdots` when `\ldots` is following and followed by two comma marks. In your situation, `\cdots` is better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are five columns in your array, however, you only provided three columns (`\begin{array}{ccc}`). Put five `c`s in the braces may solve your problem.

To typeset matrix in math mode, I strongly recommend you using `matrix` (and also `bmatrix`, `pmatrix`, `vmatrix` and `Vmatrix`) provided by the package `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
    \big[ \alpha_1,\,\alpha_2,\,\ldots,\,\alpha_n \big]
    \begin{bmatrix}
        b_{11} & \cdots & b_{1j} & \cdots & b_{1j} \\
        b_{21} & \cdots & x_{22} & \cdots & b_{1j}\\
        \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
        b_{n1} & \cdots & x_{nj} & \cdots & b_{ns}
    \end{bmatrix}
    =
    \big[ c_1,\,c_2,\,\ldots,\,c_s \big]
\]
\end{document}
```

See its output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have 5 columns, so also five elements should be in an argument of `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
 %\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
 b_{11} & \ldots & b_{1j} & \ldots & b_{1j} \\
 b_{21} & \ldots & x_{22} & \ldots & b_{1j}\\
 \vdots & \ldots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots\\
 b_{n1} & \ldots & x_{nj} & \ldots & b_{ns}
 \end{array} \right)
\end{displaymath}

Or rather

\[
\left[
 \begin{array}{ccccc}
 b_{11} & \ldots & b_{1j} & \ldots & b_{1j} \\
 b_{21} & \ldots & x_{22} & \ldots & b_{1j}\\
 \multicolumn{5}{c}{\dotfill}\\
 b_{n1} & \ldots & x_{nj} & \ldots & b_{ns}
 \end{array} 
\right]
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here every `c` means a centered column (`l` - left, `r` - right).